# How to set alignment for SpinBox in QtControls 2.0?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols2

The text alignment for text in my SpinBox is centered by default. The [SpinBox documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-spinbox.html) states that there is a `horizontalAlignment` property, but when I try to specify the horizontal alignment, I get the following error:

`Invalid property name "horizontalAlignment". (M16)`

My full SpinBox code is here:

```
SpinBox {
    editable: true
    horizontalAlignment: Qt.AlignLeft
    from: 1
    to: 10000
    value: model.numberOfElements
}
```

How would I go about aligning text in a SpinBox in Qt Controls 2.0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all the link of the docs that you point out is from SpinBox of Qt Quick Controls 1, the link of Qt Quick Controls 2 is: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-spinbox.html.

Considering the above Qt Quick Controls 2 has a docs that indicates how to customize the controls: [Customizing Qt Quick Controls 2](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-customize.html#customizing-a-control).

In the case of [SpinBox](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-customize.html#customizing-spinbox) the solution is:

```
import QtQuick.Controls 2.5

SpinBox {
    id: control
    value: 50
    editable: true
    contentItem: TextInput {
        z: 2
        text: control.textFromValue(control.value, control.locale)

        font: control.font
        color: "#21be2b"
        selectionColor: "#21be2b"
        selectedTextColor: "#ffffff"
        horizontalAlignment: Qt.AlignLeft
        verticalAlignment: Qt.AlignVCenter

        readOnly: !control.editable
        validator: control.validator
        inputMethodHints: Qt.ImhFormattedNumbersOnly
    }
}
```